# Password request redirect to another page

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I click on forgot password page

it redirect me to **http://example.com/user/password** which is fine

now when i enter email id . it redirect me to

**"http//example.com/user */**. I want it to redirect another page

**http://example.com/request-access**

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup you can try looking into the following:

1. Writing a Custom Module with a hook_form_alter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21545160/4417724
2. Login Tobboggan + Rules: Not 100% if this would work
3. Template/Re-direction: Redirect users who are not logged in away from the 'user' - if thats an option